# Upper bound of line integral along simple closed curve.

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, line-integrals

Let $U$ be an open set in $\Bbb C$ and $f\in H(U)$.

Fix a point $z\in U$.
Consider the line integral $$\displaystyle \oint_{\partial D(z,\varepsilon)} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}$$

Since $\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}$ is continuous on $U-\{z\}$ and $[0,2\pi]$ is compact,

$$\sup_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]} \lvert\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z} \rvert$$ exists and is equal to $$\max_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]} \lvert\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z} \rvert$$

Hence, $$\lvert\displaystyle \oint_{\partial D(z,\varepsilon)} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}\rvert \le \sup_{\theta\in [0,2\pi]} \lvert\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z} \rvert 2\pi\varepsilon \to 0 \;\;\text{as } \varepsilon \to 0$$

We get $\displaystyle \oint_{\partial D(z,\varepsilon)} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}=0$.

Is my argument correct?

Thanks for your helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have demonstrated that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\oint_{\partial D(z,\varepsilon)} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z} \, d\zeta = 0 \, .
$$
In order to show that the integral itself it zero you would have to show that it is independent of $\varepsilon$. That is correct but requires some justification.

It may be easier to use Cauchy's integral theorem: The function
$$
 g(\zeta) = \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z} 
$$
is holomorphic in $U \setminus \{ z \}$ with a *removable singularity* at $\zeta =z$ (because it has a limit there). It follows that $g$ can be extended homomorphically over $z$, and then Cauchy's integral theorem states that
$$
\oint_{\partial D(z,\varepsilon)} \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z} \, d\zeta = \oint_{\partial D(z,\varepsilon)} g(\zeta) \, d\zeta = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks!!  My textbook has mentioned that it has a limit at z and continuous on $U-\{z\}$, then it is bounded by some constant. But I don't know the relationship between them.

Comment: @StevenLu: Having a limit a $z$, being bounded near $z$, and being holomorphically extendable at $z$ are all equivalent, that is [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for helping!